# How to fix svg displaing in img tag doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint

I upgraded my SharePoint project from 2013 to 2019. I have `img` tag with "src" attribute that contains path to svg file. In SharePoint 2013 all image work well, but in SP 2019 doesn't work.

```
<img src="sample.svg" />
```

Comment: It should work exactly like that if the `src` path is correct. This seems to be quite a large update and probably the cause for the problem - not the `img` tag itself.
Go the browser's dev tools / network tab and do a page refresh to see the requests related to images to see if there are any problems there

Comment: I checked it out. SVG files have status 304. Any ideas why?

Comment: I solved my problem: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/11/30/common-issue-sp2019-items-in-document-libraries-are-downloaded-with-mime-type-application-octet-stream-rather-than-the-accurate-one/

Comment: Great! You can actually answer your own question with the workaround or at least the link to the solution, and accept it